# Airflow - DAG level access control

Tags: authorization, airflow

I am struggling to set up DAG level access control in Airflow 2.1.0. The aim is to let user see and control a single DAG and its runs, but nothing else. Trying to follow [docs on access control](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html) and barely documented [access_control parameter of DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html) I'm setting up a minimal scenario:

- Role `my_role` with `can read on Website`
- User `my_user` with role `my_role`
- DAG `my_dag` with `DAG(..., access_control: {'my_role': ['can_read', 'can_edit']})`

This partially works. I can log in as `my_user` and see only `my_dag` in the list of DAGs. I cannot however view the DAG clicking on it, trigger it or view its runs. I tried to add extra global permissions like `read on DAG Runs / Task Instances`, but didn't help. The only thing that worked is being able to trigger the DAG with global `create on DAG Runs` permission (I'm not sure if I'm able to trigger *any* DAG now just by issuing proper request, didn't check).

So is this possible to achieve? Am I missing something maybe?

Comment: Hey Kombajn, did you eventually find a way to use `access_control` parameter at DAG level?

Comment: The best approach I've found is using the UI, copy either the Op or User role (depending on the overall level of perms you want) and then in the copied role, remove all the `DAGs` perms. Assign that to everybody. 

Then create separate roles with read/edit perms on specific DAGs, for example you might have a 'general' role that can read/edit on every nonsensitive DAG, a 'sensitive1' role for the first group of sensitive DAGs, a 'sensitive2' role for another group, etc. You can assign multiple roles to each user, so some would only have 'general', some would also have 'sensitive1', etc.

Comment: @alete - yes, I now got back to this and following aleksanderacai's answer below it worked (with some issue with listing dag runs / task instances).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing following permissions `can read on DAG Runs, can read on Task Instances, can edit on DAG Runs, can read on DAG Code, can read on Task Logs` added to `my_role`

Also note that `access_control` attribute in DAG is outdated and is not needed anymore as you can setup that at role level with permission `can xxx on DAG:dag_id` where xxx is read or edit and dag_id is an id you set at your DAG definition

Comment: I don't understand why you say `access_control` attribute in DAG is outdated or not needed. It's on the latest documentation and is the only reasonable way to set per dag permissions from the code (and with this, highly dynamic). I don't want to add permissions dag by dag on the UI, I wan't to write a piece of code that automatically sets proper access control from the source.

Comment: Fully agree on @alete's comment on `access_control`, but apart from that I added permissions you mentioned and it *almost* works fine. [This reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html) was helpful to understand permissions required for various actions. User can view and trigger only DAGs that he's explicitly assigned via access_control. The only thing is that "List DAG Run" and "List Task Instances" don't show any records - I suppose that might be a bug.